# If $|z|=1$ how can I show that $|dz|=-i\frac{dz}{z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

if $|z|=1$ how can I show that $|dz|=-i\frac{dz}{z}$

Actually I am solving an integral in which I am supposed to use Cauchy's Integral formulae...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The circle $|z|=r$ can be parametrized by using the substitution $z=re^{is}$ where $s\in\mathbb{R}$ (radians). Then
$$\frac{dz}{ds}=e^{is}\cdot i=z\cdot i\implies |dz|=rds=r\frac{dz}{iz}=-ir\frac{dz}{z}.$$
As regards your line integral, by the [Residue Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem)
$$\int_{|z|=1}\frac{|dz|}{{|z-2|}^2}=\int_{|z|=1}\frac{1}{(z-2)(1/z-2)}\cdot \frac{dz}{iz}=2\pi\,\mbox{Res}\left(\frac{1}{(z-2)(1-2z)},z_0=?\right).$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: $\int_{|z|=1}\frac{|dz|}{{|z-2|}^2}$..thank you but still not able to carry it further

Comment: How is dt=|dz|...I dont understand

Comment: @kadir $|dz|$ is the infinitesimal arc lenght. With this parametrization $|dz|=dt$.

Comment: will it change if we change the radius of circle.

Comment: @kadir Yes, $|dz|=Rdt$ for the circle $|z|=R$.

Comment: What if someone uses the parametrization $z=e^{2\pi it}$? Then your method seems to fail.

Comment: @stressedout What do you mean?

Comment: @RobertZ: if I follow your steps in the first displayed formula one at a time beginning with $z = \exp(2it)$ I get $dt = -i\,dz/(2z)$. So if $|dz| = -i\,dz/z$, you must be using something beyond the fact that the circle can be parameterized as $z = \exp(it)$.

Comment: If you were actually computing $dz/ds$, then I would need to divide $dz/dt$ by $ds/dt$, which would cancel out the 2 in my calculation - is that what is going on? I am rusty about the notation $|dz|$

Comment: Then $2dt=|dz|$. $dt=|dz|$ when we use radians

Comment: @RobertZ I think $|dz|=ds$, not $dt$. Carl Mummert noticed it first though,

Comment: @RobertZ I'm sorry - like I was saying, I'm rusty.  We should be able to use any parameterization we want, right? So if I use $z = \exp(2it)$, somewhere in the calculation I should need to cancel a 2.   The first displayed formula in the answer doesn't show someone like me how to make that cancelation.

Comment: I revised my answer. Is it clear now?

Comment: Thanks, that does solve my concern, if we do the entire calculation with respect to an arc length parameter