# On the behavior of $|\mathrm{d}z|$ in complex integration

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I saw in a problem book that

> $$|dz| = -\frac{ir}{z}dz$$
> when $|z|=r$.

So, I tried to prove it. First, I argued that $|dz|^2 = dz\cdot\overline{dz}\,$ and $\overline{dz}=d\overline{z}$. Then I calculated $d\overline{z}$ by expanding it assuming the Leibnitz property for $d$:

$$0=dr^2=d|z|^2=d(z\cdot\overline{z})=z\cdot d\overline{z}+ dz\cdot \overline{z}\implies d\overline{z} = -\frac{r^2}{z^2}dz$$ Then taking square roots from both sides gives

$$|dz| = \sqrt{-\frac{r^2}{z^2}dz^2}=\pm\frac{ir}{z}dz$$

I didn't know how to overrule the solution with $+$ sign. So, any help is appreciated about how to choose the right sign. An alternative proof is welcome too.

But that aside, I read in one of the comments by @RobertZ under [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2318341/436477) that $|dz|$ gives the infinitesimal arc-length. If so, then it seems intuitively expected to have

$$\int_{|z|=r}d|z|=\color{red}{2\pi r}$$

which is correct (I had made a mistake previously). So, I read that $|dz|=dt$ but I found no justification for this. I'll appreciate it if someone explains why $|dz|=dt$ where $t$ denotes any parameterization of the curve $|z|=r$.

Comment: Why $\int_{|z|=r}d\overline{z}=2\pi r$? We have that $\int_{|z|=r}|dz|=\int_{|z|=r}-\frac{ir}{z}dz=2\pi r$.

Comment: @RobertZ That was a typo. I made two mistakes: a mistake in typing the question, and another mistake in calculating another integral because I had made a typing mistake lol xD By the way, did you see my comment under your answer in the linked question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minus sign comes from the fact that in the formula we usually have a $\frac{1}{i}$ which is precisely $-i$; a simple proof using polar coordinates: $z = re^{i\theta}$, $dz = ire^{i\theta}d\theta = i(\frac{z}{r})(rd\theta)$, so inverting and noting that $|dz| = rd\theta$ we get the formula you want.

There is no contradiction since indeed $\int_{|z|=r}d|z|={2\pi r}$ by inspection, while both $\int_{|z|=r}dz= \int_{|z|=r} d\bar{z} = 0$ by a simple computation or Cauchy (and conjugation)...

Comment: Sorry, I totally missed $|dz|=rd\theta$ part. (+1) So, $|dz|$ is in fact $ds$, not $dt$. Right?

Comment: no problem - we can easily prove $|dz| = rd\theta$, as by definition $|dz| = \sqrt{((dx)^2+(dy)^2)}$ and use $x=r\cos{\theta}$, $dx=-r\sin{\theta}d\theta$ etc

Comment: $ds$ and $d\theta$ coincide when $r=1$, but otherwise you need the scaling since the arclength measures the "intrinsic" (geometric if you want) length of the curve regardless of parametrization